# Apache2 Proxy Pass Include all parameters on URL

Tags: apache2, proxypass

Is it possible to have a proxy pass on Apache2 that also carries the parameters passed to backend servers?

Example:

```
www.frontserver.com -> www.frontserver.com (meaning that on the base directory it will not be proxied to any backend servers.)
```

It will be proxied IF it's under /_nuxt Directory

```
www.frontserver.com/_nuxt/index.js -> backserver.com/_nuxt/index.js (dynamicaly)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ProxyPassMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch) which match regular expression

```
ProxyPassMatch "^_nuxt/(.*)" "http://backserver.com/_nuxt/$1"
```

Comment: Is it possible inside VirtualHost Element?

Comment: ProxyPassMatch directive can be used in VirtualHost context

Answer (score 0):

You can use [P flag of mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) for this task:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^_nuxt/(.*)" "%{ENV:protocol}://backserver.com/_nuxt/$1" [P]
```